# Canvas drawing only occupies 1/3 of the screen

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

Im making a simple drawing app using canvas. The problem is when I set a background image (of a black board) for the canvas, it only occupies ~66% of the screen. See screenshot/link:
[Canvas View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mEy4.png)

I want my canvas view to occupy the entire screen except the bottom part that RelativeLayout with id parLayout occupies.

What am I doing wrong in my code? Here is what I have:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int wandToUse1;
public static int wandToUse2;
public static int wandToUse3;

private ViewGroup rootLayout;
private ViewGroup rlWand2;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
private RelativeLayout pl;
private RelativeLayout wn2;
private RelativeLayout wn1;
ImageView w1;
ImageView w2;
boolean clicked1 = false;
boolean clicked2 = false;
RelativeLayout ll;
public static int X;
public static int Y;
CanvasView canvasView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parLayout);
    canvasView = new CanvasView(MainActivity.this);
    rootLayout.addView(canvasView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1w2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight() / 2);
    layoutParams1w2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    canvasView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1w2);

    ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parLayout);
    w1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wand1);
    w2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wand2);
    w1.setImageResource(wandToUse1);
    w2.setImageResource(wandToUse2);

    pl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordAct);
    wn1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlw1);
    wn2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlw2);

    w1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    w2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
}

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}

public class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!clicked1) {
            rootLayout = (ViewGroup) w1.getParent();
            if (rootLayout != null) {
                rootLayout.removeView(w1);
            }
            rlWand2 = (ViewGroup) w2.getParent();
            if (rlWand2 != null) {
                rlWand2.removeView(w2);
            }

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
            pl.addView(w1);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1w2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250);
            wn2.addView(w2);


            layoutParams1w2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

            w1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
            w2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1w2);

            clicked1 = true;
            clicked2 = false;
        }
        X = (int) event.getRawX();
        Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                canvasView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                break;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

CanvasView.java

```
public class CanvasView extends View{
private Bitmap sourceBitmap;
private Canvas sourceCanvas = new Canvas();
private Paint destPaint = new Paint();
public static Path destPath = new Path();
Bitmap rawBitmap;
public int width;
public int height;

public CanvasView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;

    //converting drawable resource file into bitmap
    rawBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.blackboard);

    rawBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rawBitmap, width, height, false);
    Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    RectF whereToDraw = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
    //converting bitmap into mutable bitmap
    sourceBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rawBitmap.getWidth(), rawBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    sourceCanvas.setBitmap(sourceBitmap);
    sourceCanvas.drawBitmap(rawBitmap, frameToDraw,whereToDraw, null);

    destPaint.setAlpha(0);
    destPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    destPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    destPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    destPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    //change this value as per your need
    destPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    destPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    sourceCanvas.drawPath(destPath, destPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

public void clearCanvas() {
    destPath.reset();
    invalidate();
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            destPath.moveTo(MainActivity.X, MainActivity.Y-360);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            destPath.lineTo(MainActivity.X, MainActivity.Y-360);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordAct"
tools:context="com.simplepaintapp.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#BA9DF7"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/parentLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlw1"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/wand1"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@mipmap/pen" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlw2"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/wand2"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/eraser" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I was a bit tired yesterday and couldn't think.
Just fix this line in MainActivity.java

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1w2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight() / 2);
```

To

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1w2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
```